# new onedrive api - uploading file to an item(Folder) error

Tags: onedrive-for-business, office365apis

I'm working on a little console app to be able to upload document to a folder(item) using the new onedrive api [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/readme.htm)

I can easliy upload to the root of my onedrive like so

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Centralpark.jpg:/content
```

but what do i need to upload to a particular folder (Item i think is used)

According to the doc one of this should work :-

```
PUT /drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
PUT /drive/root:/{parent-path}/{filename}:/content
PUT /drive/items/{parent-id}/children/{filename}/content
```

But how do i get the **parent-id** or the **parent-path**

I have created a folder called Test
But when used as below

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Test:/myFilename.txt:/content
```

i get error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "Paths can only contain at most two colons"
  }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Worked it out.Probably was too tired.
This worked
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Test/myFilename.txt:/content

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. Probably was too tired. This worked:

```
api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Test/myFilename.txt:/content
```